# Cucumber + Akephalos "UNIXServer is required"

Tags: javascript, cucumber, automated-tests, rvm, akephalos

I setup a rails 2.3 project with cucumber and it works fine. Now i wanted to run javascript tests and i set it up using Akephalos. Now the funny thing. The tests run on my collegues machines just fine.

We are using RVM + ruby 1.8.7 + gemsets + bundler. Gems are all installed but whenever i start a specific feature on my machine like this:

```
bundle exec cucumber featues/myfeature.feature
```

It says:

```
LoadError: UNIXServer is required
(root) at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/unix.rb:5
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1037
auto_load at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/unix.rb:826
open_server at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:794
initialize at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1377
start_service at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1665
start! at /Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/akephalos-0.2.4/lib/akephalos/server.rb:29
(root) at -e:1
```

My machine is a 2011 MacBook Pro i7 quadcore with snow leopard, homebrew, rvm, ruby, rvm infp says:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace:

system:
  uname:       "Darwin ChrisBookPro.local 10.7.3 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.3: Sun Mar  6 13:37:56 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.14.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
  bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
  zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"

rvm:
  version:      "rvm 1.2.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

ruby:
  interpreter:  "ruby"
  version:      "1.8.7"
  date:         "2011-02-18"
  platform:     "i686-darwin10.7.3"
  patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 patchlevel 334"
  full_version: "ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.7.3]"

homes:
  gem:          "/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace"
  ruby:         "/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334"

binaries:
  ruby:         "/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby"
  irb:          "/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/irb"
  gem:          "/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/gem"
  rake:         "/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/bin/rake"

environment:
  PATH:         "/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/bin:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global/bin:/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin:/Users/christoph/.rvm/bin::/Users/christoph/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/share/java/jruby/bin:/Developer/SDKs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools"
  GEM_HOME:     "/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace"
  GEM_PATH:     "/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global"
  MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334"
  IRBRC:        "/Users/christoph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/.irbrc"
  RUBYOPT:      ""
  gemset:       "betterplace"
```

Unpacking the jruby-jar reveals: the drb is included. Manually requiring works to. But i can't figure out, what the problem is. With further investigation i was able to figure out, what the actual java commandline is, that is supposed to bring the akephalos server up:

```
java -Xmx128M -cp /Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-core-1.6.0.jar:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar org.jruby.Main -I vendor:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/akephalos-0.2.4/lib:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/akephalos-0.2.4/src -r akephalos/server -e 'Akephalos::Server.start!("/tmp/akephalos.1586.sock")'
```

The error stays the same:

```
LoadError: UNIXServer is required
(root) at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/unix.rb:5
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1037
auto_load at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/unix.rb:826
open_server at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:794
initialize at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1377
start_service at file:/Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/jruby-jars-1.6.0/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/drb/drb.rb:1665
start! at /Users/christoph/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@betterplace/gems/akephalos-0.2.4/lib/akephalos/server.rb:29
(root) at -e:1
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Cheers, Christoph